# Implicit data conversion from string to int in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a procedure which inserts data to table. I declared the values to be inserted to table(input parameters) as Varchar type. But the column type for 2 columns in table got changed to Int type. But still procedure is inserting values properly.(The columns IssuerId and Employer Id are int type in underlying table IssuerGroupIDMapping.)
IMPORTANT question for me is will the procedure fail in some specific scenario,I already check in C# so that only valid integers are passed to proc. 
Do i need to change the code right away.(Bit of an issue for me as procedure is already in production and seems to be working.). PLEASE suggest.

Below is my procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [uspInsertIssuerGroupIDMapping]
@EmployerID Varchar(25),    
@IssuerID Varchar(25),  
@PlanID Varchar(25),    
@IssuerGroupID Varchar(25), 
@CreateUserID Varchar(25)

*****/
AS

BEGIN TRY

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    --check to see if a duplicate trigger exists
    IF ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [IssuerGroupIDMapping] 
                             WHERE EmployerId = @EmployerID AND PlanId = @PlanID)
                    )

    BEGIN


        INSERT INTO [IssuerGroupIDMapping]
               ([EmployerId]
               ,[IssuerId]
               ,[PlanId]
               ,[IssuerGroupID]
               ,[CreateUserId]
               ,[CreateDate]
               ,[UpdateUserId]
               ,[UpdateDate]
               )
         VALUES
               ( 
                 @EmployerID
                ,@IssuerID
                ,@PlanID
                ,@IssuerGroupID
                ,@CreateUserId
                ,(SELECT Framework.udfGetTimeTravelDate())
                ,@CreateUserId
                ,(SELECT Framework.udfGetTimeTravelDate())
               );

               SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --if a duplicate record exists update it
            UPDATE [IssuerGroupIDMapping] SET 
                                 IssuerId = @IssuerID
                                ,IssuerGroupID = @IssuerGroupID
                                ,UpdateDate = (SELECT Framework.udfGetTimeTravelDate())
                                ,UpdateUserId = @CreateUserID

            WHERE EmployerId = @EmployerID
                                    AND PlanId = @PlanID

            SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

        END
```

Comment: make sure you pass a *number* between -2147483648 *and* 2147483647 for those parameters. Anything else will crash.

Comment: I can't envision a scenario where it isnt more efficient to swap "varchar(x)" for "int" in the SP param declaration. It is very very low risk and I would certainly want the SP to throw an error if I passed a geniuine varchar in the circumstances you describe. You could even cast the varchar param to int explicitly in the SP before inserting and handle any conversion errors with TRY / CATCH.

Comment: You may also want to know about the `MERGE` statement

Comment: @user2159471 Please check the updated answer , as i got something that will be useful in your current situation or for future reference .http://www.sanssql.com/2011/12/deadlock-implicit-conversion_14.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL allows you to do this by casting your varchar to type Int , However a better advice would be to do some validation on your front end so that any unwanted value do not create any problems in your queries (Since it's in Prod. already i hope you have taken care of it.).

Sql implicitly converts your varchar into int , so i don't think you have to worry about anything but filter you inputs so that you don't fetch any string to your procedure which can not be converted into Int and as **kaf** suggested anything between   `-2147483648 and 2147483647` you don't need to worry about .

Well thanks for accepting answer but i think you need to look at this also ..

SQL server internally uses a function **‘CONVERT_IMPLICIT’** to do conversion and when the conversion happens the **INDEXES**  are not used effectively due to the uncertainty involved in the result of the function – which means it has to convert the value for each and every row. This results in SQL Server scanning the entire table looking for the value.

A fine article [here](http://www.sanssql.com/2011/12/deadlock-implicit-conversion_14.html)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue that you are going to run into with this conversion is performance.  SQL can figure out what you're trying to do with implicit conversions.  However, it will be unable to use indexing and statistics to their full advantage.

In a large dataset, *which no database starts out as but successful ones usually grow into*, you could run into major performance problems.

Read this excellent article by SQL Server expert Tibor Karaszi:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/04/28/match-those-types.aspx